# Scheduler on a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, server

I am trying to create a "kind-of" scheduler in a server using servlets that will expect an input from a user (Day/Month/Year) and will execute the event when the calendar reaches this day.

I implemented this by using ScheduledExecutorService through Java for my servlet.

```
{cnt.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

      public void  run() {

     if(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==day && c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)== hour)
     {
      try {

      //implemented code in here
    }
```

However, I think that this might load my servlet a lot (as it is a thread that will run for x days until it reaches the final day).
Can you propose a different method or a different librady that will be more efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
1. dump all the incoming tasks to a DB.
2. fetch the tasks from DB periodically:
    E.G., fetch the tasks from DB every day for daily tasks.
3. put those tasks into your scheduler. You will have threads running up to the interval you setup.
    E.G., if you fetch them daily, then it will be maximum 24 hours.
```

Comment: Very good idea. What if I create the DB with the events that are not equal to this day and at the end of each day (let's say 12:01) I run a method that will check if the event's day that is stored in the DB is equal to the current day, extract this event and then run the scheduler for this day? Will it be more efficient?

Comment: Please note, that if you have multiple applications running, then you will have to add some sort of state and locking to prevent the task from being executed twice.

Comment: @JoseMartinez It will just be one application.